# Connecting Postgresql to Rails in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

So I recently deployed my `Rails` backend server to `Heroku`.
After a little struggling with passing from `SQLite` to `PostgreSQL`, I finally got everything running.
Now the problem is, I did `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate` and that went without any errors but now when I make a `REST` call to the server I have this error (complete) :

```
2019-07-31T19:42:16.534355+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-31T19:42:16.534259 #4]  INFO -- : [047c870d-8791-4ec7-90df-a7998b8b17c5] Started POST "/sessions" for 91.176.204.35 at 2019-07-31 19:42:16 +0000
2019-07-31T19:42:16.535824+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-31T19:42:16.535063 #4]  INFO -- : [047c870d-8791-4ec7-90df-a7998b8b17c5] Processing by SessionsController#create as */*
2019-07-31T19:42:16.535947+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-31T19:42:16.535882 #4]  INFO -- : [047c870d-8791-4ec7-90df-a7998b8b17c5]   Parameters: {"email"=>"titivermeesch@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
2019-07-31T19:42:16.566455+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-31T19:42:16.566340 #4]  INFO -- : [047c870d-8791-4ec7-90df-a7998b8b17c5] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 11.2ms)
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567845+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-07-31T19:42:16.567772 #4] FATAL -- : [047c870d-8791-4ec7-90df-a7998b8b17c5]   
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567954+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-07-31T19:42:16.567879 #4] FATAL -- : [047c870d-8791-4ec7-90df-a7998b8b17c5] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567957+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567959+00:00 app[web.1]:                                           ^
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567961+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567962+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567964+00:00 app[web.1]:                      c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567965+00:00 app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567966+00:00 app[web.1]:                 LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567968+00:00 app[web.1]:                 LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567969+00:00 app[web.1]:                 LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567971+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567972+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567973+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2019-07-31T19:42:16.567975+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2019-07-31T19:42:16.568064+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-07-31T19:42:16.568002 #4] FATAL -- : [047c870d-8791-4ec7-90df-a7998b8b17c5]   
2019-07-31T19:42:16.568171+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-07-31T19:42:16.568104 #4] FATAL -- : [047c870d-8791-4ec7-90df-a7998b8b17c5] app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

I have a `PostgreSQL` add-on installed and it is running. (Otherwise the `Rails` server wouldn't even boot).

So why do I get this kind of errors on each request? I checked in console and if I do something like `User.all` I get this :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist)
LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT $1
                               ^
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT $1
```

This gets me so confused, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may have run `rake db:migrate` locally and not on Heroku. As a result, when you use the Heroku CLI, it doesn't recognize the users table because it doesn't yet exist.

I believe if you use have the `pg` gem in your Gemfile, Heroku's system will automatically setup a database for you. It's been a while since I've created a Heroku instance so don't quote me on that.

If you're unsure if you have PostgreSQL with your app, check the app's service add-ons area. Heroku also has more [documentation on using PostgreSQL on their platform.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) It may be a good idea for you to reference their [documentation for getting started with Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5) as well.

Once you have your PostgreSQL database setup to work with your app, you use the Heroku CLI to migrate the database and create your users table:

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I thought that it was directly transferred, really thanks for that

Comment: Ya you have to provision postgres when creating the app in the resources section. Then you have to manually migrate each time you deploy. One way around that is to create a Procfile with a release script that is run each time you deploy. This can include the command to `rake db:migrate` on each deploy if needed. Also it would be `heroku run rake db:migrate` if running from the command line. You need to include the `run` command to access the toolbelt.